# What are the differences between %0.3lf and %3lf?

Tags: c

I know that %0.3lf tells printf() the length of the number to print, and when I Googled the meaning of %3lf I got the same explanation, although they don't work the same at all, as you can see in the next piece of code:

```
double a = 1.234;

printf("%0.3lf\n", a);
printf("%3lf", a);
```

the output is:

```
1.234
1.24000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `"1.24000"` the true output? Or are you missing some characters?

Answer (score 3):

The number before the `.` (or if no `.`) is the *field width*.  This specifies a minimum number of characters the output will generate.  If the output size is less that this, it is padded on the left with spaces.

The number after the `.` is the *precision*.  For a floating point number with the `%f` format, this specifies the number of digits to print after the decimal point.

Comment: The `0` before the `.` is a flag, not a field width.  See also this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67373146/what-are-the-differences-between-0-3lf-and-3lf#comment119088052_67373227).

Answer (score 2):

> I Googled the meaning of %3lf

You can find information about C library functions on cppreference.com. (It's also a reference to C++, so make sure the page says "C" and not "C++" in the top left corner.) [It's `printf` page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is the source of the passages quoted below.

---

The `3` in `%3lf` is a field width.

> integer value or `*` that **specifies minimum field width.** The result is padded with *space* characters (by default), if required, on the left when right-justified, or on the right if left-justified. In the case when `*` is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type `int`, which appears before the argument to be converted and the argument supplying precision if one is supplied. If the value of the argument is negative, it results with the `-` flag specified and positive field width. (Note: This is the minimum width: The value is never truncated.)

The `0` in `%0.3lf` is a flag to specify that zeroes should be used to pad the number to the minimum field width. It's useless since no minimum field width was specified. It's possible the author believed it was a field width.

> **for integer and floating point number conversions, leading zeros are used to pad the field instead of space characters.** For integer numbers it is ignored if the precision is explicitly specified. For other conversions using this flag results in undefined behavior. It is ignored if `-` flag is present.

The `.3` in `%0.3lf` is a precision.

> `.` followed by integer number or `*`, or neither that specifies *precision* of the conversion. In the case when `*` is used, the precision is specified by an additional argument of type `int`, which appears before the argument to be converted, but after the argument supplying minimum field width if one is supplied. If the value of this argument is negative, it is ignored. If neither a number nor `*` is used, the precision is taken as zero. See the table below for exact effects of precision.

> [For `f`] ***Precision* specifies the exact number of digits to appear after the decimal point character.** The default precision is `6`. In the *alternative implementation* decimal point character is written even if no digits follow it. For infinity and not-a-number conversion style see notes.

(Emphasis mine in all cases.)

Comment: Actually, the `0` before the decimal point is not a field width; it is a flag, indicating that the field should be padded with leading zeros to the width — but there isn't a width so the `0` is pointless.  Using `%.3lf` would produce the same result.  Only if you use something like `%08.3lf` does the `0` become relevant and change the output.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Of course. Fixed. It's very easy to think it's the field width when there is no field width.

Answer (score 1):

`%0.3lf` means print with precision of 3 points after decimal

`%3lf` means print with a width of at least 3 wide

Answer (score 1):

`%0.3lf` means 3 digits after the radix point of that double data.
`%3lf` doesn't provide special usability as `%3lf` will provide the exact same output as `%lf`.

Comment: `%3lf` will provide the exact same output as `%lf`... true but requires an explanation. As a matter of fact `%4lf` might produce different output from `%lf`, can you explain how?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same output there too. [Check it here](https://ibb.co/Hx3xV0n)

Comment: You should get the same output for finite values, yet the output will differ for `inf` and `nan`, which will be padded to 4 characters with an initial space for `%4lf` but not for `%lf` :)

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

1. the width modifier `l` has no effect on `f` conversion specifier. `float`s are converted to double.

[image]
2. Width and precision:
[image]
3. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/MGaGxrr1E

Comment: *`float` numbers are converted to `double`.*... More precisely: `float` values are implicitly converted to `double` when passed as extra arguments to a vararg function such as `printf`.